# PostgreSQL 9.5.1 fails to install on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, bitrock

Both 64 bit and 32 bit installers fail with the message:

```
There has been an error.
The environment variable COMSPEC does not seem to point the cmd.exe or there
is a trailing semicolon present. Please fix this variable and restart installation.
```

I checked the COMSPEC variable and there doesn't seem to be a problem. I double checked with:

```
%COMSPEC%" /C "echo test ok"
```

Everything seems ok. I am lost here. Couldn't find anything to help. I am also attaching the installer log:

```
Log started 03/15/2016 at 10:37:37
Preferred installation mode : qt
Trying to init installer in mode qt
Mode qt successfully initialized
Executing D:\TEMP/postgresql_installer_79c6abfe43/temp_check_comspec.bat 
Script exit code: 1

Script output:


Script stderr:
 '"D:\TEMP\POSTGR~1\TEMP_C~1.BAT"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Error running D:\TEMP/postgresql_installer_79c6abfe43/temp_check_comspec.bat : '"D:\TEMP\POSTGR~1\TEMP_C~1.BAT"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: got the exact same problem on windows 8.1 as well